# Magento 1.8.1 / Category layout for specific categories

Tags: magento, inheritance, navigation, categories

I am working on Magento 1.8.1 site and have a problem, for which I hope to find the solution here - after googling for several days.

I want to set different/custom page layout for category and its child categories, but I am stuck.

So, I have a 2-level category:

First category (for example CLOTHES) has a default 2-column page layout (because I want to have an additional navigation).

I would like that second category (for example LEVIS) would have 1-column page layout, but it's impossible to set it. It overrides all subcategory specific settings, it just accepts parent category settings.

I tried will all various possible settings, even with another theme. I also disabled inheritance of page layout from parent category.

Is this a known bug or did I do something wrong?

Thanks for your help,
B

Comment: Same problem here. 1.8.1.0, using Argento theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily set different layout for each category
just go to `manage category` and select category and go to `custom design tab`
and set use `Use Parent Category Settings to no` and set `page layout according` to your design just see image

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, Keyur. I already tried this before, but Magento still inherits parent category settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify values of "Use Parent Category Settings" and "Page Layout" under "Custom Design" tab of category, then Magento uses default page layout from layout xml file (under layout folder of theme).

If you want to specify custom layout for particular category, then you need to specify it for that category.

For example "CLOTHES" is your parent category and "LEVIS" is child category (for which you want to set different layout).

Then you need to specify values of "Use Parent Category Settings" to "No" and "Page Layout" to whatever layout you want to set for specific category.

Just save it and you can see reflection on front-end[image].

please refer screen-shots if you have any problem.

Let me know if you have any query.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohit, my settings are the same as in your screenshots, but apparently there is a setting, which forces my Magento to inherit parent category settings by default. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a Magento thing, or Argento, as I'm unable to revert to the default theme. Anyway, what ended up working was a Custom Layout Update for the category:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in 1.7.0.2 as I had the same problem and this fixed it.

For each Category that is inheriting that should not be
Set "Use Parent Category Settings" to "Yes", save, then set it back to "No" and save.

You might also want to check that Store view settings are not overriding global view settings

Hope that helps someone.